# angular.json search and copy files into one directory

Tags: angular, configuration

I want to search files (*.md) in several subdirectories (projects/rufma-styleguide/src= and copy the found files to a new directory (markdown) without specifying the path.

```json
"assets": [
  {
    "glob": "**/*.md",
    "input": "project/src",
    "output": "markdown"
  },
```

### input - project structure

- project

- project/src/page/colors.md
- project/src/page/typography.md
- project/src/component/button.md

### output

- markdown/colors.md
- markdown/typography.md
- markdown/button.md

No matter how I try, the full path is always stored in the output directory for all files.

What's wrong?

Comment: I believe the reason this can't be achieved is naming conflicts. Say you have page/color.md and component/color.md. One file would overwrite the other.